# Change in Java coding required restart Tomcat everytimes

Tags: java

Everytimes, I change the java coding in java class under Eclipse. I click the run-as, it requires to restart the embedded Tomcat server in order to make the change effective. How can I test the change without the need to restart the Tomcat server. Because it is very time-consuming, if I need to restart the embedded Tomcat server whenever I change some coding. It will spend one minute for testing a little change.

Thanks

Comment: It takes 1 min mine takes only 5 sec to 10 sec

Comment: Hook your debugger to tomcat and make sure 'Project -> Build automatically' is checked. That will cause most of the changes to be injected on running code every time a change is saved and recompiled. If changes cannot be injected by the HotSpot jvm you will get a message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If i am not wrong there is a option to do that. I am pretty sure that you have seen that.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a **hot deploy**:

> Hot-deployable services are those which can be added to or removed
>   from the running server. It is the ability to change ON-THE-FLY what’s
>   currently deployed without redeploying it.
>
> Hot deployment is VERY hot for development. The time savings realized
>   when your developers can simply run their build and have the new code
>   auto-deploy instead of build, shutdown, startup is massive.

And good news there is a hot deploy in Eclipse. Just Follow the [Eclipse tutorial for this](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 2):

This process is called `hot swap` or also `hot deploy`. There are tools that do this process for you. One open source tool that you can check is [HotSwapAgent](http://hotswapagent.org/). One paid alternative would be [JRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).

Obviously goes without saying that these two are far from comparable in terms of features and efficiency. But if it is just for testing purposes the open source alternative is just fine. In industry, not that much(we have tried it in my company and didn't fit our expectations).